# Coloring a cell red when the email is in a bad format

Tags: vba, excel

how color my cell in red when my email has a bad format like screeshot http://prntscr.com/ilgbcd?

```
    Function EmailValide(ByVal strEmail As String) As Boolean
    Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    ' We create a regular expression
    Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    ' We define the criteria to respect for an e-mail
    re.Pattern = "w+([-+.']w+)*@w+([-.]w+)*.w+([-.]w+)*"

    'The RegExp.Test function returns True if the email meets the criteria

      EmailValide = re.Test(strEmail)

    End Function
```

Comment: Please give example of valid and invalid e-mails..

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code calling `EmailValide()` would be something:

```
Dim myCell As Range
...
Set myCell = Range("...") ' set myCell in some way
...
```

then you can use:

```
If EmailValide(myCell.value) Then myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Comment: how can i use macro not fucntion to check the format ?

Comment: what's you code till now? do you only have that function?

Comment: screenshot for my function  http://prntscr.com/ilgyny  I want to use macro for when i want to click button check, it check the email format

Comment: what button? where is it placed (is it an Excel Button or a Userform Button)? etc.. Please edit your question to give a decent picture of your environment, needs, attempts and issues. this is the only way you can hope and get a helpful answer

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ilh41k  you can see the screenshot i want to use button to check the format o email so , how can i change my function on top .did you understand me @Display Name ?

Comment: can you please send me a message on this mail helann1234@gmail.com  to send the problem entirely.